# Validity of a first-order formula

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

How can I see (and prove) whether the given first-order formula $\varphi$ is valid or not?

$\varphi = \forall x \forall y [ (r(x,y) \rightarrow (p(x) \rightarrow p(y))) \land (r(x,y) \rightarrow (p(y) \rightarrow p(x)))]$

Comment: It is clearly not valid; it is enough to build an easy counter-example with a domain with an object $a$ such that $p(a)$ does hold and an object $b$ such that $p(b)$ does not and, in addition, that $r(a,b)$ does hold. This is enough to "falsify" the first conjunct.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, I choose $\mathbb N_0$ as my Domain. $I(x) = 0$, $I(y)=1$. Moreover the meaning of predicate $p$ is "is even". The meaning of the predicate $r(x,y)$ is $y$ is greater than $x$, and I am done?

Comment: Perfect ! because $(0 < 1) \to (Even(0) \to Even(1))$ is $True \to (True \to False)$ that "evaluates" to $False$.

Comment: yay! Can I ask you yet another question, just to be sure: If I replace $r$ in $\varphi$ by $\doteq$ (equality), so now I am considering also the theory of equality and its axioms, then the formula becomes valid. So, each instance of $r(x,y)$ gets replaced by $x \doteq y$. My assumption is that, then the formula is valid. because $x$ and $y$ are equal and according to the predicate substitution axioms of equality theory $p(x)$ and $p(y)$ always evaluates to the same truth value. Is this kind of the right (formal) argument?

Comment: Yes; in this case you are nor more free to choose an interpretation for $r(x,y)$ and we have two cases : if $x \ne y$, then the two conditionals are vacuously true, irrespective of the "values" of $p$; when $x=y$ - as you noted - axioms for equality guarantee us that $p(x)$ and $p(y)$ both hold or both do not.